# "The procedure entry point GetErrorMode could not be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll" error occur while running .exe on win2k3

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, windows-server-2003

I am building my c++ project on win2k3 server with vs2008. I can compile my project successfully. 
But while running it's.exe on win2k3 it is giving error as "The procedure entry point GetErrorMode could not be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll"

Answer (score 2):

[GetErrorMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679355%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is supported by Windows Vista and later. The minimum server version is 2008.

Comment: I have modified terget version header file to win2k3. minimum required platform  in.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you've modified on your build system - you still link with the full import library from the SDK. It only matters what functions are actually implemented in `kernel32.dll` on the target machine.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So,What should I do to run vs2008 complied .exe's on win2k3?

Comment: You cannot use this function on Win2k3. Either you use it via GetProcAddress or you cannot use this program on this OS.

Comment: Use [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to try to obtain a pointer to the function and if it fails your code should behave accordingly. Or just tell the user that your program requires Windows 2008 or later.

Comment: Shouldn't it be sufficient to modify the project's target OS version? It will set `_WIN32_WINNT` and `WINVER` so that the compiler will skip the function declaration in the API header, and the program won't compile anymore (because `GetErrorMode` will be an undeclared identifier). It won't matter that the lib file still knows how to import the function since the function will never be called.

Comment: @RobKennedy, it should be, unless the compiler generates implicit function prototypes. Then it should fail at link time with unresolved symbol error because of the name mangling applied to `__stdcall` functions.